# File not being found because of a space in it

Tags: python

Ok so I'm writing a script that opens files but when there is a space it doesn't recognize that there is more to the path afterwards.

```
import os
OpenFile = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\file name.txt'
os.system(OpenFile)
```

This is the code being used but it gives the error (Notice it doesn't include the name.txt after file)

```
'C:\Users\Me\file' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module and give the command as a list and all these problems will go away.

Comment: Umm... I don't really know how to use the subprocess module... Do you know how I would do it?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) comes with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the caret character (`^`) to escape spaces in file path. Just add it before the space.

```py
import os
OpenFile = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\file^ name.txt'
os.system(OpenFile)
```

By using this the space in the filename does not disrupt the program from opening the file. This approach is way easier than using `subprocess` module. Your file should open now using this code.

Answer (score 0):

you just need `'"..."'` to pass the string (`"..."`) to the shell.

```
import os
OpenFile = '"C:\\Users\\Me\\file name.txt"'
os.system(OpenFile)
```